# how to create Nested XML in C#

Tags: c#

I want to create nested xml so that the result would look like:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><TASKLOADLOG>
<PERSON>
<EMAIL>data</EMAIL><LOADED>OK</LOADED><LOADERROR>ABC</LOADERROR>
</PERSON>
<PERSON>
<EMAIL>data</EMAIL><LOADED>OK</LOADED><LOADERROR>ABC</LOADERROR>
</PERSON>
<PERSON>
<EMAIL>data</EMAIL><LOADED>OK</LOADED><LOADERROR>ABC</LOADERROR>
</PERSON>
</TASKLOADLOG>"
```

I wrote following code and It crashed in a loop

```
XmlDocument XmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xDeclare = XmlResponse.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
XmlElement documentRoot = XmlResponse.DocumentElement;
XmlResponse.InsertBefore(xDeclare, documentRoot);
XmlElement el = (XmlElement)XmlResponse.AppendChild(XmlResponse.CreateElement("TASKLOADLOG"));

List<XmlElement> ls = new List<XmlElement>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    ls[i].AppendChild(XmlResponse.CreateElement("EMAIL")).InnerText = "data";
    ls[i].AppendChild(XmlResponse.CreateElement("LOADED")).InnerText = "OK";
    ls[i].AppendChild(XmlResponse.CreateElement("LOADERROR")).InnerText = "ABC";
}

MessageBox.Show(XmlResponse.OuterXml);
```

I don't now how to define `PERSON` what I need to write to fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple, you are not creating the PERSON node. Email, Loaded and LoadError should be child nodes to Person node.

Edit:

just to let you know, you could even use class Serialization for the XML you are trying to generate.

For Example:

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Loaded { get; set; }
    public string LoadError{ get; set; }
}

Person p = new Person
{
    Email = "abc",
    Loaded = "abc";
    LoadError = "abc"
};
new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person)).Serialize(Console.Out, Person);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks about the quick answer

I wrote following code and It got error in  XmlResponse.Root.AppendChild :

```
    XmlDocument XmlResponse = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration xDeclare = XmlResponse.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
XmlElement documentRoot = XmlResponse.DocumentElement;
XmlResponse.InsertBefore(xDeclare, documentRoot);
XmlElement el = (XmlElement)XmlResponse.AppendChild(XmlResponse.CreateElement("TASKLOADLOG"));

//List<XmlElement> ls = new List<XmlElement>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
     XmlResponse.Root.AppendChild(new XElement("PERSON",
            new XElement("EMAIL", "data"),
            new XElement("LOADED", "OK"),
            new XElement("LOADERROR", "ABC")
    )));
}



MessageBox.Show(XmlResponse.OuterXml);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is crashing because you are referencing the first index of your list **ls** when the list is empty.

Create your document like this:

```
var doc = XDocument(new XElement("TASKLOADLOG"));

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    doc.Root.AppendChild(new XElement("PERSON",
            new XElement("EMAIL", "data"),
            new XElement("LOADED", "OK"),
            new XElement("LOADERROR", "ABC")
    )));
}
```

Comment: You should explain how this code is different from the OP's code.